# Jenkins 'execute windows batch build step' use 32bit cmd.exe

Tags: jenkins, cmd, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm using Jenkins to run a VBScript that updates test results in Quality Centre (ALM).

When I run it from 32 bit `cmd.exe` (`C:\windows\syswow64\cmd.exe`), the VBScript works fine.  When I run it from the default 64-bit `cmd.exe` (`c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe`), it fails to create the ALM object.

`Set alm = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")`

It seems that Jenkins' 'Execute Windows Batch Command' build step uses the default 64-bit command line on the slaves.  How can I make Jenkins use the 32 bit `cmd.exe`?

thanks

Glenn

Answer (score 1):

Try forcing the PATH so that the C:\windows\syswow64\cmd.exe appears before the C:\windows\ system32\cmd.exe one. You can either change the PATH on your Jenkins SLAVE (depending how you start it the solution will differ), or maybe even change your VBScript using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072423/changing-to-remove-path-from-env-variable-path)

Comment: Could you explain how can we change this path in jenkins? Which configuration file I should change?